# Trouble with Project Euler 22

Tags: java, debugging

So, I'm playing with Project Euler and am having trouble with my code. This is not complete, I have yet to venture into actually reading the a file. For now I am just using an ArrayList that holds a few of the words. Here is my code:

```
public static void euler22test(){ //flaw somewhere in this
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(read()); //gets information from file
    int sum = 0;
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //for calculating namescore
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){ //for item in list
        String word = list.get(i); //gets string at index i in array
        for (int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++){ //for each letter in word
            int wordSum = 0; //the sum for current word
            char c = word.charAt(k); //gets letter for each index of word
            for (int a = 0; a < alphabet.length(); a++){ //checks what letter it is
                if (c == alphabet.charAt(a)){ //if they are the same
                    wordSum += alphabet.indexOf(c) + 1; //gets place in alphabet
                    sum += wordSum * i; //adds wordSum * place in list to sum.
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Actual: 1720"); //what it should print out
    System.out.println("Calculated: "+sum); //prints 1295
}
public static ArrayList<String> read(){//reads from file
    //currently just returns the below list
    //will eventually read from a file
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("MARY");//5
    list.add("PATRICIA");//6
    list.add("LINDA");//4
    list.add("BARBARA"); //1
    list.add("ELIZABETH");//2
    list.add("JENNIFER");//3
    list.add("MARIA");//4
    return list;
}
```

As the comments say, when ran, this prints out 1290. I've hand calculated that the real value is 1720. Here is my math:

```
BARBARA
wordSum: 1(2+1+18+2+1+18+1)
sum: 43
ELIZABETH
wordSum: 2(5+12+9+26+1+2+5+20+8)
sum: 219
JENNIFER
wordSum: 3(10+5+14+14+9+6+5+18)
sum: 462
LINDA
wordSum: 4(12+9+14+4+1)
sum: 622
MARIA
wordSum: 5(13+1+18+9+1)
sum: 832
MARY
wordSum: 6(13+1+18+25)
sum: 1174
PATRICIA
wordSum: 7(17+1+20+18+9+3+9+1)
sum: 1720
```

I can't exactly find the error in the code.

Comment: Well, order doesn't really matter with addition. Also, am I not? I alphabetized them. Just like how the program would.

Comment: Upon looking at the code, it appears I am an idiot. I did not in fact sort it. However, this changes the result to 1285, still not what I manually calculated. I'm using java.util.Collections.sort(ArrayList) to sort it.

Comment: That has no effect on the result. It stays 1285.

Comment: So is that the problem? How exactly do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things wrong with your code. First of all, you add wordSum to Sum after calculating the value of each character instead of after calculating the entire wordSum value for a name. The wordSum value should also be multiplied by i + 1 instead of i because i starts at 0. Here is the fixed code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { //flaw somewhere in this
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(read()); //gets information from file
    int sum = 0;
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //for calculating namescore
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { //for item in list
        String word = list.get(i); //gets string at index i in array
        int wordSum = 0; //the sum for current word
        for (int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++) { //for each letter in word
            char c = word.charAt(k); //gets letter for each index of word
            for (int a = 0; a < alphabet.length(); a++) { //checks what letter it is
                if (c == alphabet.charAt(a)) { //if they are the same
                    wordSum += alphabet.indexOf(c) + 1; //gets place in alphabet
                }
            }
            System.out.println(wordSum);
        }
        sum += wordSum * (i+1); //adds wordSum * place in list to sum.
    }
    System.out.println("Actual: 1713"); //what it should print out
    System.out.println("Calculated: " + sum); //prints 1295
}
```

Also, it appears that you made a mistake when hand calculating the value. The "P" in PATRICIA should be 16 not 17 leading to a total of 1713.